# How to run a migration in Appcelerator Alloy

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app using Titanium Appcelerator and using the Alloy Framework. I have run the following command and generated a migration file (20120926011253_User.js) in my app/migrations folder:

```
alloy generate model User sql name:string phone:string gender:string last_updated:datetime
```

How can I run this migration and actually create the tables in the SQLite db? I couldn't find how to do this online and have tried the commands I could think of. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You dont have to worry about running migrations. 
After you generate model+migration files and compile ,alloy takes care of running migration when you start your app.

see these generated files to get a better idea : /Resources/alloy/model/*.js for the generated models.
In these files, alloy  calls MODEL.M function,which is defined in  in  /Resources/alloy.js.

MODEL.M calls *beforeModelCreate*,which in turn calls *InitAdapter*,which is where the DB is inited.
the default DB that alloy uses is  '_alloy_'  for each app.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Migration Tutorial using Titanium Studio

http://bit.ly/AlloyMigration